# When connecting python and mysql database error occurs

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

This Error happens....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tushar Gaurav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 509, in open_connection
    self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Tushar Gaurav/Desktop/Pratical Implementation-1.py", line 3, in <module>
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",passwd="")
  File "C:\Users\Tushar Gaurav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\__init__.py", line 179, in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tushar Gaurav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Tushar Gaurav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Tushar Gaurav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
    self._socket.open_connection()
  File "C:\Users\Tushar Gaurav\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\network.py", line 512, in open_connection
    errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Comment: try using `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` also check if mysql's port is set to `3306`

Comment: Tushar Gaurav...